# TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment vriable in Kaggle

Tags: python, nlp, kaggle

I am running the following code in Kaggle. The language set is "Python". Trying to do perform NLP on a paragraph and create visuals using the code below.

```
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



import pandas as pd
import itertools
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import  word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk import RegexpParser
document= """The BBC has been testing a new service called SoundIndex, which
            lists the top 1,000 artists based on discussions crawled from Bebo,
            Last.fm, Google Groups, iTunes, MySpace and YouTube. The top five
            bands according to SoundIndex right now are Coldplay, Rihanna, The
            Ting Tings, Duffy and Mariah Carey , but the index is refreshed
            every six hours. SoundIndex also lets users sort by popular tracks,
            search by artist, or create customized charts based on music
            preferences or filters by age range, sex or location. Results can
            also be limited to just one data source (such as Last.fm).
        """
sentences = sent_tokenize(document) 
sentences = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences] 
sentences = [pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
sentence = list(itertools.chain(*sentences))
#grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}"
grammar = """
           NOUN_VERB_NOUN: {<DT>?<VB>*<NN.*>+}
           GRUND_NOUN: {<VBG.><NN.*>+}
           VN:{<VBN><NN>+}
           NOUN_AND_ADJ: {<NN>?<JJ>*<NN.*>+}
                         {<N.*|JJ.*>*<N.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns
           NOUN_PHRASE: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}
           ADJ_PHRASE: {}
           KEYPHRASE: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}
           KEYWORDS: {<NN.*>}
           VERB_PHRASE: {<VB.*><NP|PP|CLAUSE>+$} # Chunk verbs and their arguments
           CLAUSE: {<NP><VP>}
           """
cp = RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(sentence)
#print(result)
result.draw()
for subtree in result.subtrees():
        #if subtree.label() == "NOUN_VERB_NOUN": 
            #print("NOUN_VERB_NOUN: "+str(subtree.leaves()))
        print(str(subtree.label())+"  "+str(subtree.leaves()))
result.draw()
return(result)
```

The error I am getting on execution is:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Could anyone please assist on how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you import `matplotlib` if you don't use it.

Comment: why do you use `return` if you didn't define function .? `return` is used only inside own functions.

Comment: as for me `result.draw()` doesn't uses `matplotlib` to display window with image but it uses directly `tkinter` and probably you can't change it.

Comment: in documentation [nltk.draw.util](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.draw.html#module-nltk.draw.util) I found that it uses `Tkinter.Canvas` to display it - so it is not `matplotlib` and you can't stop it. You can only skip `result.draw()`. Maybe there is function to save it in file and display from file but I don't know it.